# How do I change the finished Animation in different positions for different displays Swift

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a growing Animation that ends in the right position in an Iphone 8 but completely wrong in other displays, how do I adjust the final position depending on display model.

The Animated imageView is on top of another ImageView so I cant set constraints to that view correctly as its an overlap.

this is my current code

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {
    self.cardImage.frame = CGRect(x: 277, y: 210, width: 85, height: 135)
})
```

here are 2 screen shots iphone 8 is correct but on the same starting X and Y its wrong for the other displays

[image]

[image]

Comment: share screenshots of two different displays.

Comment: @MumtazHussain here are the screen shots of both 8 and 11 models ..

Comment: The problem is in `x: 277, y: 210`, well I think on this bases your whole UI is having problem. If you see closely, your magician guy's cape is positioned parallel to the curtains behind in iPhone 8, while in other device it is different. I suggest you need to get a good idea of auto-layouts.

Comment: @MumtazHussain I know exactly what the problem is regards to the X and Y what I dont know how to approach is the final animation ending positions ..  I can resize the Magician and resize the stage imageview, but I cant constrain the card as its on top of the magician imageview ... could you please point me int the right direction on how to approach this. I am new to Swift and I cant find any info in the problem in Auto layout research .. I have looked